# Replacing all text

Tags: javascript

How would I replace every single word on any given web page client-side with whatever `var cms` is?
It doesn't matter what js dependencies are needed, or if links break.

Comment: you need to more specify your question.

Comment: So if `cms` is "test", and the page has `<body>Hi there, how <i>are</i> you?</body>`, is your expected result `<body>test test, test <i>test</i> test?</body>` or just `<body>test</body>`? Please update your question to include a detailed example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
function htmlreplace(a, b, element) {    
    if (!element) element = document.body;    
    var nodes = element.childNodes;
    for (var n=0; n<nodes.length; n++) {
        if (nodes[n].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var r = new RegExp(a, 'gi');
            nodes[n].textContent = nodes[n].textContent.replace(r, b);
        } else {
            htmlreplace(a, b, nodes[n]);
        }
    }
}

htmlreplace('a', 'r');
```

Comment: How do I make it match **every** single lone word? Not just one string Like "a test sentence" would become "xxx xxx xxx"

Comment: `nodes[n].textContent = nodes[n].textContent.replace(/\w+/g, b);`

Answer (score 1):

may you are talking about this :

```
var myOldString = "Hello username! I hope you enjoy your stay username.";
var myNewString = myOldString.replace(/username/g, "pranay");
```

Comment: @jmoon - you can try repace function on whole page content like i applied on the string........

Comment: I need it to match *EVERYTHING*, not one string. Like document.body.replace("new word here");